# Could not resolve view, Spring MVC integration with freemarker

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I was trying integrate Spring framework with freemarker views, but i have some issues that i can't resolve.

I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/springmvc] 
threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'appServlet'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'appServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1190)
```

this is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }
}
```

And my views storeds in `WEB-INF/views`:
this is `home.ftl`:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello world!  
</h1>

<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
</body>
</html>
```

I think, is a problem with the `servlet-context.xml`, so here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <!-- freemarker config -->
    <beans:bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--
      View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. If you need
      different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the resource bundle resolver.
    -->
    <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
      <beans:property name="cache" value="true"/>
      <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
      <beans:property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.springmvc" />



</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the prefix option from the viewResolver bean

```
<beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</beans:bean>
```